# What is the difference between VCPU and CPU in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

What is the difference between 1 `VCPU` and 1 `CPU` in google cloud. How to fetch the CPU count and VCPU count for a list of compute instances using GCP client libraries

Comment: Please read the very first paragraphs in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms I don't see what better explanation you would expect on here.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, neither means anything in the cloud. You must read the details for the machine type that you are configuring. A machine type might provide 2 vCPUs but only provide 0.5 CPUs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, 1 vCPU is not equal to 1 CPU. A vCPU is a virtual CPU that is assigned to a VM. A CPU is a physical chip that is installed in a computer.

In Google Cloud, a vCPU is typically equivalent to one physical CPU core. However, there are some machine types that use hyperthreading, which means that a single vCPU can be used to run two threads simultaneously.

So, if you have a machine type that uses hyperthreading, then 1 vCPU will be equivalent to 2 physical CPU cores.

To fetch the CPU count and vCPU count for a list of compute instances using GCP client libraries, you can use the following code:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
instances = compute.instances().list(project='newProject').execute()

for instance in instances['items']:
 cpu_count = instance['machineType']['numCpus']
 vcpu_count = instance['vcpus']
 print('Instance {} has {} CPUs and {} vCPUs'.format(instance['name'], cpu_count, vcpu_count))
```

Comment: Typo: Change to: 1 physical CPU core will be equivalent to 2 vCPUs.